# get reference to the element that calls slides()

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

Is there a way to get reference to the element that calls the `slides()`?

Example code:

```
$('#my_slideshow').slides({
  animationStart: function() {
    <reference_to_myslideshow>.something();
  }
});
```

Using `$(this)` returns the created slides object which is this:

```
[
Object
animationComplete: function (current) {
animationStart: function () {
autoHeight: false
autoHeightSpeed: 350
bigTarget: false
container: "slides_container"
crossfade: "true"
currentClass: "current"
effect: "fade"
fadeEasing: ""
fadeSpeed: 350
generateNextPrev: false
generatePagination: true
hoverPause: false
next: "next"
pagination: true
paginationClass: "pagination"
pause: 0
play: 7200
preload: false
preloadImage: "/img/loading.gif"
prependPagination: false
prev: "prev"
randomize: false
slideEasing: ""
slideSpeed: 350
slidesLoaded: function (){}
start: 1
__proto__: Object
]
```

rather than the actual `$('#my_slideshow')` object, which I don't seem to get be able to get a reference to.

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
$(this).something();
```

and you can find answer of these question on little search

Comment: this returns the slides object and not the $('#my_slideshow') jquery object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `$(this)` for the jQuery object, or `this` for the plain DOM node:

```
$('#my_slideshow').slides({
    animationStart: function() {
        var callingElement = $(this), // jQuery object,
            callingElementDOMNode = this; // DOM node
            // hence:
        $(this).something();
        }
    });
```

Also, as an addenda, please note that I've closed the string for the selector in the initial parentheses.

Comment: $(this) does not return the $('#my_slideshow') object, rather the created Slides object

Comment: Is `slides()` a plug-in? Can you link to its documentation page(s)?

Comment: http://slidesjs.com/ is the plugin. I suspect that somehow it must pass reference to the methods animationStart etc on the constructor, so they can actually be referenced from there.

Comment: I found a way, I updated the function signatures to pass the actual element, like so option.animationStart(elem); and that makes it available in the calling code later. I'll be writing a full answer soon.